# For $X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, is $\frac{1}{n+\delta}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, for $\delta>0$, consistent for $\mu$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, consistency

For $X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, suppose we define an estimator for $\mu$ as

$$
\theta_n = \frac{1}{n+\delta}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$

for some $\delta>0$. Intuitively it appears it is consistent. If $\delta = 0$, we have for every $\epsilon >0$,

$$
\Pr\!\left[\,|\theta_n-\mu|\geq\varepsilon\,\right] = 
    \Pr\!\left[ \frac{\sqrt{n}\,\big|\theta_n-\mu\big|}{\sigma} \geq \sqrt{n}\varepsilon/\sigma \right] = 
    2\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}\,\varepsilon}{\sigma}\right)\right) \to 0
$$

But I am unsure how to account for $\delta>0$. Is there a simple way it holds upon the structure above?

Comment: You can compute this probability explicitly as $$\Pr(|\theta_n-\mu|\ge \varepsilon)=\Pr\left(|\frac{\sum (X_i-\mu)}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\delta\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}|\ge\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}(n+\delta)\right)$$ because $Z = \sum (X_i-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{n})$ has a standard Normal distribution. This event is the complement of the interval bounded by $\delta/(\sigma\sqrt{n})\pm (\varepsilon/\sigma)\sqrt{n}+\varepsilon\delta/(\sigma\sqrt{n}).$ You can now see that its endpoints expand toward $\pm\infty$ (they are proportional to $\sqrt{n}$), implying the probability shrinks to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just do
$$
\theta_n = \frac 1{n+\delta}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \frac n{n+\delta} \bar X_n
$$
so by the weak law of large numbers
$$
\bar X_n \stackrel{\text{p}}\to \mu
$$
and then
$$
\frac n{n+\delta}\to 1
$$
so the product converges in probability to $\mu$ as well (you could cite Slutsky's theorem for this and the fact that convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to the same constant).